# Перевод кода C++ в C# - C#

Tags: c#, c++, кодировка

народ помогите перевести это в C#
я не знаком c#

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define nmax 100
void main()
{
int a[nmax][nmax];
int i,j,n,s=0;
int max, min;
clrscr();
printf("n manin engiz->");
scanf("%d",&n);
for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
for (j=0;j<n;j++){
printf("a[%d][%d]=",i,j);
scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
}
}
max=a[0][0];
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
for (j=0;j<n;j++){
if (a[i][j]>max){
max=a[i][j];
}
}
s=s+max;
max=a[0][0];
}
printf("\nOndelgen massiv \n");
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
for (j=0;j<n;j++){
printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
}
printf("\n");
}
printf(" max sum = %d\n",s);
getch();
}
```

Comment: Познакомьтесь и сами переведите. А если вам и знакомиться не надо - копите деньги и идите к фрилансерам за переводом.

Comment: А зачем надо то?

Comment: И можете сказать в общем, что делает ваш код? Я так понимаю, он считает сумму максимальных чисел во всех рядах.

Comment: Вы тут с ума посходили? Какой перевод у фрилансеров? Какое бюро переводов? Какой "закрыть вопрос"? Тут школьник просит свою программу на C++ написать на C#.  Вопрос вполне адекватный!

Comment: @Mr.Don'tknow, с чего ты взял, что программа его? Он мог найти первое попавшиеся и выложить сюда для переводов. Вметсо того, что бы задать вопрос с конкретными проблемами он бросил сюда куда.

Comment: @iluxa1810, почему вы все такие нудные... Мы такие мудрые люди, блин! Комментарий №1 - Идите к фрилансеру, чтобы перевести с C++ на C# программу которая просто считает сумму максимальных. Комментарий № 4 - закрыть вопрос, потому что это же так сложно -
 написать простейший алгоритм на С#.

Comment: @Mr.Don'tknow, если такое не присекать, то сюда набежит толпа школьников. Зачем поощрять лень? Если парень не приложил никаких усилий, что бы решить свою задачу, то может быть ему не место в этой сфере?

Comment: @iluxa1810, ну да-да, я знаю, что здесь полностью профессиональный FAQ. Но я просто представил себя на его месте... Я школьник. Я знаю C++, но надо написать на C#. Я написал код на C++, а в школе просят на C#. А у меня ещё русский язык, математика... Времени нет! И задаю вопрос))) Будет обидно если среди профессионалов никто не ответит на мой вопрос.

Comment: @Mr.Don'tknow: Да-да, если нет времени учиться, нужно страдать. Не бывает такого, что преподаватель объяснял C++, и вдруг даёт задание на C#. Незнание языка, на котором нужно делать задание, происходит от того, что ученик вместо уроков гоняет в футбик.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Вроде должно помочь...

```
using System;
namespace Willi
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n=0;
            Console.Write("Введи N: ");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[,] arr = new int[n, n];
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("Input array[{0}][{1}]: ", i ,j);
                    arr[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }
            int max, summax = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                max = arr[i, 0];
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    max = Math.Max(arr[i, j], max);
                }
                summax += max;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} ", arr[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Сумма максимальных: {0}", summax);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо огромное взял книжку и сделал сам                                                                                                                                                                             c         onst int nmax = 100;
            int[,] a = new int[nmax, nmax];
            int i, j, n, s = 0;
            int max, min;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("n manin engiz->");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());